# How to retrieve header parameters in cxf WebService from Request?

Tags: grails, plugins, http-headers, request, cxf

I have grails (v 2.4.0) project with cxf plugin(cxf 2.0.1) installed.

I need to get authentication data which are sent in Request Header.
How can I get those Header Parameters from Request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [Application Authentication With JAX-WS](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/)